# Best Practice to store CurrentUser

Tags: javascript

I'm currently playing with node.js

with some frameworks like passport i can resolve the authenticated user.
Now i read the user from the database and got an object with the following data

```
{
 id: '23123123211',
 name :'foo',
 mail : 'foo@foo.com'
}
```

Are there any well known places where the current user should be stored?

In .net i wouldto something like

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = myPrincipal;
```

I can't see find conventions about this. Is there a place where most node.js developer would expect an current user instance?

As an alternative i would assign it to the request object (for other middlewares) and to some kind of context, which is accessible for other objects outside the middleware context.

Does this sound as a good or bad idea?  Any suggestions ?

Comment: You could use a framework, which provides a session. Or write your own mechanism for it.

Comment: To use a framework that supports session is a good way, I think express.js is benifit for you